# How to disable"Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" checkbox from the API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-devops-rest-api

I am creating a pipeline using definition API with the "`Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here`" checkbox checked by default, which stops the YAML file from its normal trigger option.

How do I change the definition API request to create it with the "`Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here`" unchecked, or is there an API to disable it ?

Note: I don't want to use branch filters. I just want to use the trigger that I wrote in the YAML file, which is being overridden by this checkbox.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Rest API: [Pipelines-Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), it has no parameters can control the trigger option: **Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here**

> how do i change the definition api request to create it with the Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" unchecked, or is there an api to disable it ?

You can change to use the Rest API: [Definitions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to create the Pipeline definition and set the option: **Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here**  at the same time.

Here is an example:

Rest API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=7.1-preview.7
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "triggers": [
        {
            "branchFilters": [],
            "pathFilters": [],
            "settingsSourceType": 2,
            "batchChanges": false,
            "maxConcurrentBuildsPerBranch": 1,
            "triggerType": "continuousIntegration"
        }
    ],
    "process": {
        "yamlFilename": "azure-pipelines.yml"
 
    },
    "repository": {
        "id": "{repoid}",
        "type": "TfsGit",
        "name": "{reponame}",
        "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/main",
        "clean": null,
        "checkoutSubmodules": false
    },
    "quality": "definition",
    "name": "{definitionname}",
    "type": "build",
    "queueStatus": "enabled"


}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you can use the Rest API to disable the option: [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

Rest Api:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=7.1-preview.7
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "triggers": [
        {
            "branchFilters": [],
            "pathFilters": [],
            "settingsSourceType": 2,
            "batchChanges": false,
            "maxConcurrentBuildsPerBranch": 1,
            "triggerType": "continuousIntegration"
        }
    ],
    "process": {
        "yamlFilename": "azure-pipelines.yml"
 
    },
    "repository": {
        "id": "20cfaec6-39f3-4a2d-868d-492f1cee5ae3",
        "type": "TfsGit",
        "name": "test1031",
        "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/main",
        "clean": null,
        "checkoutSubmodules": false
    },
    "id": 1042,
    "quality": "definition",
    "name": "test10317",
    "type": "build",
    "queueStatus": "enabled",
     "revision": 4

}
```

**Note:** Every time it is updated, the revision will be increased by 1. You can refer to [my ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65027909/how-to-update-azure-devops-build-definition-source-from-azure-repos-to-github-us/65031268#65031268).